Existence of a linear equation in n variables
I have a question regarding a linear system that contains a single linear equation in n variables, that is, in the following form: $$a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + \cdots + a_nx_n = b$$
Where $a_ 1, \cdots, a_n$ and $b$ belong to the real numbers. In that sense, if there exists some $a_i = 0, i = 1, \cdots , n$; would the linear equation then become in $n - p$ variables? Where $p$ is equal to the number of coefficients $a_i$ equal to zero.

Thanks, I understand that. Now, however, if they mention to you in a text that a linear equation has, for example, 5 variables, they implicitly tell you that none of the coefficients that accompanies that variable is zero, right?

No, $x+y=3$ is the equation of a plane in three dimensions.  A plane in space is different from a line on the $x,y$ plane, although they have the same equation.  What do you want to do with the equation?

So it depends on the context where $x + y = 3$ is indicated, which is either a line or a plane? Interesting, the question is really out of curiosity, it is not about some homework.
